# Stuck on virtual zoo

Tags: object, netbeans

I'm doing a virtual zoo in computer science and i'm stuck.  We are using a guide to navigate through the zoo, but I can't figure out how to go without getting errors. When I run it it says "Null! Null, and I have no idea what to do. I am pretty new to coding so thank you for your help.

```
class Guide {
private String name;
int Selection;
int Selection1;
int Selection3;
int Selection2;
int choice;
Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner (System.in);

void welcomeusertozoo() {

      System.out.println("Hello! Welcome to Cringe Jarin! A Zoo full of cringy creative creatures. Im Fred. What is your Cringy Name?");
 name = inputScanner.next();
System.err.println("Ewww..... How cringy. Well, Welcome " + name + "! What creatures would you like to visit First?"
        + "\n 1.Ogres"
        + "\n 2.Vampires"
        + "\n 3.Rats \n\n" );
choice = inputScanner.nextInt();
    creatureselection(choice);
}

void creatureselection(int Selection) {

    switch (Selection) {

        case 1: System.out.println("Plug up the nose and close those eyes! These creatures are Ugly! who Would you Like to visit...\n Please press 1 to go meet the commander himself, Ogre E Lee. \n Please press 2 to go meet the one and only Ogrewall Jackson. \n Please press 3 to meet the wonderful Mr.GreenBean. \n Please press 4 to meet the rebellious William Shrallace. \n\n");
          choice = inputScanner.nextInt();

        switch (choice){
            case 1: System.out.println("Commander Ogre. E Lee Here! \n\n");  
            case 2: System.out.println("This is the impeccable, the amazing, one and only Ogrewall Jackson \n\n"); 
            break;
            case 3: System.out.println("This is the fashionable, the sexy, the fabulous GreenBean \n\n"); 
            break;
            case 4: System.out.println("This is the free, the bravest heart I know, the impecable William Shrallace \n\n"); 
            default: System.out.println("We do not have a creature under that selection at the moment. Please choose 1 or 2 or 3 \n\n");

        }

        break;


        case 2:System.out.println("Dont have a scarf? Oh.... watch your necks! Who would you like to visit...\n Please press 1 to go meet the spooky Dio. \n Please press 2 to go meet the truly bone chilling Diego. \n Please press 3 to meet the bloodthirsty Big White Bat. \n Please press 4 to meet the Bold Mubat. \n\n");
         choice = inputScanner.nextInt();
        switch (choice){
            case 1: System.out.println("Dio \n\n"); creatureselection(2);
                break;
            case 2:  System.out.println("Diego \n\n"); creatureselection(2);
                break;
            case 3:  System.out.println("Big White bat \n\n"); creatureselection(2);
                break;
            case 4:  System.out.println("Bold Mubat \n\n"); creatureselection(2);
                break;
                default: System.out.println("We do not have a creature under that selection at the moment. Please choose 1 or 2 or 3 \n\n");
            creatureselection(2);
        }


        break;


        case 3:System.out.println("Pull out the Cheese but dont let it rip! These creatures are Cringy! Who would you like to visit...\n Please press 1 to go meet the Odd Ratty Weisau. \n Please press 2 to go meet the backstabbing Risa. \n Please press 3 to meet the permanently sad Dindin. \n Please press 4 to meet the sketchy Markymouse. \n\n");
         choice = inputScanner.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:  System.out.println("Ratty Weisau \n\n"); creatureselection(3);
                break;
            case 2:  System.out.println("Risa \n\n"); creatureselection(3);
                break;
            case 3:  System.out.println("Dindin \n\n"); creatureselection(3);
                break;
            case 4:  System.out.println("Markymouse \n\n"); creatureselection(3);
                break;
                default: System.out.println("We do not have a creature under that selection at the moment. Please choose 1 or 2 or 3 \n\n");
            creatureselection(3);
        }
            break;
         default: System.out.println("We do not have a creature under that selection at the moment. Please choose 1 or 2 or 3 \n\n");
            creatureselection(1);


    }



}
void setName(String fred) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be the problem? 
Can you provide more information on what is the problem. 
It seems to be working.

Are you creating a Guide object?

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Guide guide = new Guide();
        guide.welcomeusertozoo();
    }
}
```

After that everything seems to be working.
Just make sure that you have breaks on every case, just to assure consistency.
Hope I've helped.

Comment: There are 3 superclasses and for each one there is going to be 4 subclasses. You have to be able to choose which one you would like to see, and then come back to make another choice. That is one problem...The second problem is that null thing I was saying.

Comment: I can't replicate your Null problem, since everything is working fine here, to make another choice you should add a new function where you ask what the user wants to see now, and invoke that function after the switch. That would mean that when the user makes the first choice, and after seeing the subclass it would ask the user what he wants to do now. Instead of calling the creatureSelection() you would call that new function.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not very good at this, but how do you call the function?

Comment: I think this is what you intend to build, I just organized your code http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdExxNk5ZTlZsU1U

Comment: Alright so I tried that but on my main project it says "method welcome user to zoo in class guide cannot be applied to given types"

Answer (score 0):

This is the main :

```
public class ZooProject {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Rat RattyWiseau = new Rat ();
    Ogre OgreELee = new Ogre();
    Vampire Dio = new Vampire ();     
    Guide Fredtheguide = new Guide ();




    //ask user for name
    RattyWiseau.setName("Ratty Wiseau");
    Dio.setName("Dio");
   // Fredtheguide.setName("Fred");
    OgreELee.setName("Ogre E Lee");
   Fredtheguide.welcomeusertozoo();
    System.out.println(OgreELee.getName());

}

}
```